# How to loop on Python 3.4.2?

Tags: python, python-3.4

In my Python code, I have a part where I would like to repeatedly print a question if it doesn't match what I want it to.

```
name1 = input("A male name (protagonist): ")
    if name1.endswith (('ly', 's')):
        print("Sorry mate, this doesn't seem to be a proper noun. Try it again.")
        name1 = input("A male name (protagonist): ")
```

How do I make it repeatedly print out name1 if it ends with 'ly' or 's'?

Comment: This is very simple: change 'if' to 'while'.  Are you really unfamiliar with loops?  If so you might want to invest in a Python beginner's guide, or a general introduction to programming.

Comment: Also, I can think of several male names that end in 's' and 'ly'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
while True:
    name1 = input("A male name (protagonist): ")
    if name1.endswith(('ly', 's')):
        print("Sorry mate, this doesn't seem to be a proper noun. Try it again.")
        continue
    break

print("Input name is:", name1)
```

This will loop over until `if name1.endswith(('ly', 's'))` is true.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It wont. `if name1.endswith(('ly', 's'))` must be true for `continue` to execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop. While loops will continuously perform something as long as it's specified condition is true.

If you don't want a name that ends with `ly` or `s`, you can make a `while` loop like so:

```
while True:
    name1 = input("A male name (protagonist): ")
    if name1.endswith ('ly', 's'):
        print("Sorry mate, this doesn't seem to be a proper noun. Try again. ")
    else:
        break # This will exit the loop, when you have a name that doesn't satisfy the condition above
```

I should also mention that because the `if` statement was satisfied, it will restart the loop. Once the name does not end with `ly` or `s`, it will move to the `else` block, which will come out of the loop. Note that the `break` is the word that forces out of the loop.

Comment: Could you please write out the code with this loop acquired?

Comment: There it is! Done! :)